# persistentFooterButtons move above keyboard

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have been searching everywhere to try and find out how to get persistentFooterButtons to move above keyboard when a textfield is selected but I haven't had any success. The persistentFooterButtons works perfect when the keyboard isn't active

```
persistentFooterButtons: [
        ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                enableFeedback: true,
                minimumSize: const Size(double.infinity, 45)),
            onPressed: !userInteracts()
                ? null
                : () {
                    _submit();
                  },
            child: const Text('Continue'))
      ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better use a Column, with 2 childs.
The first a expanded(flex: 1) with a singleScrollView
and the second with your footer button or widget ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have to wrap your content inside a container with a bottom margin that match with the height of the keyboard. To do that, you need to make use of the `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets`. This method get the parts of the display that are completely obscured by system UI, typically by the device's keyboard.

Code sample:

```
 Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
            bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
        width: double.infinity,
        child: FilledButton.icon(
          onPressed: () {
              submitForm();
          },
          icon: const Icon(Icons.check),
          label: const Text("Save"),
        ),
      )
```